# IntPtr on a 32-bit OS and UInt64 on a 64-bit OS

Tags: c#, interop

I'm trying to do an interop to a C++ structure from C#. The structure (in a C# wrapper) is something like this

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct SENSE4_CONTEXT
{
    public System.IntPtr dwIndex; // Or UInt64, depending on platform.
}
```

The underlying C++ structure is a bit abnormal. On a 32-bit OS, `dwIndex` must be `IntPtr` in order for the interop to work, but on a 64-bit OS, it must be `UInt64` in order for the interop to work.

How can I modify the above structure to make it work on both a 32-bit and 64-bit OS?

Comment: Are you talking about the *operating system*, regardless of whether you're running in WOW64 or not? Because in a 32-bit process, `IntPtr` will be 32-bit and 64-bit in a 64-bit process...

Comment: @codeka, I'm talking about 32 or 64 bit *process*. I want to run as 32 bit process on 32 bit OS, and 64 bit process on 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "dw" prefix in `dwIndex` is accurate then it sounds like a `DWORD`, which is a 32-bit *unsigned* integer. In that case you need to use `UIntPtr`, which will be like `UInt32` on 32-bit and like `UInt64` on 64-bit.

It seems unlikely that your C++ program requires a signed integer on a 32-bit platform and an unsigned one on a 64-bit one (though not impossible, of course).

Comment: A `DWORD` type is a 32-bit unsigned integer regardless of whether or not the OS is 32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

In a 64-bit process, an `IntPtr` should be marshalled exactly the same as a `UInt64`.
Make sure to set your Target Platform to Any CPU.

To treat it as a UInt64 in C#, you can write

```
UInt64 value = (UInt64)s.dwIndex.ToInt64();
```

If you need to run as a 32-bit process, you'll need to declare two different versions of the `struct`, and two different overloads of the methods that take it, and select one of them using an `if` statement.

Comment: That's the problem; an `IntPtr` should be marshalled as `UInt64`, but it's not.

Comment: What's the difference?  They're both eight bytes.

Comment: Do you mean it needs to be unsigned? In that case, you can use `UIntPtr`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uintptr%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @SLaks, there should be no difference. But I don't know why I got such a problem.

Comment: What *is* the problem exactly?

Comment: SLaks is correct. To interop there is no difference between a UInt64 and an IntPtr on a 64 bit process.

Comment: @SLaks, the difference is that if you use `IntPtr` in place of `UInt64`, the code might fail to run.

Comment: @Ngu: That does not make sense. Do you know how it is passed differently or how it fails?

Comment: @SLaks, I don't, partly because I don't have access to the underlying C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a compiler directive/platform detect, then do a common `typedef`:

`typedef indexType IntPtr`

or

`typedef indexType UInt64`